# How can I use LINQ to select a property and also other items of a list at the same level?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of `IJapaneseDictionaryEntry` objects which are described below.  Inside this are `IKanji` objects.

```
public interface IJapaneseDictionaryEntry
{
    int Sequence { get; }
    IEnumerable<IKanji> Kanjis { get; }
    IEnumerable<IReading> Readings { get; }
    IEnumerable<ISense> Senses { get; }
}
```

Where each object contains a list of `IKanji` objects

```
public interface IKanji
{
    string Text { get; }
    IEnumerable<KanjiInformation> Informations { get; }
    IEnumerable<Priority> Priorities { get; }
}
```

I selected the data with this query:

```
List<IJapaneseDictionaryEntry> entries = dictionary.GetEntries().ToList();
```

I know how to do a simple query like this:

```
var a = entries.SelectMany(x => x.Kanjis);
```

and how to select just the text:

```
var a = entries.SelectMany(x => x.Kanjis).Select(x => x.Text);
```

But what I would like to see the text and the priorities and I am not sure how to do that. What I would like to do is to get a flat output like this:

```
kanji1  ichimango1  Newspaper1  frequency10
```

How can I select, order and flatten out the priorities with a select?

Something like this:

```
var a = entries.SelectMany(x => x.Kanjis)
               .Select(x => x.Text, Priorities1, Priorities2, Priorities3);
```

Note that there may be no entry for Priorities1, Priorities2 or Priorities3

[image]

Comment: try anonymous types or [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) (need C# v.7.0)

Comment: Yes I do have 7.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to create an anonymous object with the properties you want to return:

```
var a = entries.SelectMany(x => x.Kanjis)
               .Select(x => new { x.Text, x.Priorities });
```

As per your EDIT: If you want to get only those `Kanjis` which have a `Priority` at all, you need to add a `Where` after the `Select`:

```
var a = entries.SelectMany(x => x.Kanjis)
               .Select(x => new { x.Text, x.Priorities })
               .Where(x => x.Priorities.Any());
```

However I would suggest to call `ToList` on `x.Priorities` in order to avoid iterating the same collection twice just to determine if there are elements at all. Technically you **could** also use the `Where` in front of the `Select`, but in this case you´d lose the ability to call `ToList` to avoid those multiple iterations.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying.  I think that would be a good start for me.  I will try that and then I think I need to work out how to get data out of that object.

Comment: You can of course call `ToList` on `x.Properties` in order to materialize the list. Anyway you can just use `a.First().Priorities` to get the `Priorities` of your first `Kanji`.

Comment: @Alan2 you can get data just like with any other object - by property. `a.First().Text` or `a.First().Priorities`

Comment: Thanks for all of your help.  LINQ seems to be very powerful and I'm still very much at the learning phase.

Comment: I have another question I would like to ask soon. I'd like to find out how to construct a query that would only return an entry if there were any priorities as not all of the records have even one priority.